Ordinals multiplication: Does $a^2 b^2=b^2a^2$ imply $ab=ba$?
I found this question in one of set theory past exam: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two ordinals such that $\alpha^2\beta^2=\beta^2\alpha^2$, does it necessarily imply $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$?
Clearly if $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$ then certainly $\alpha^2\beta^2=\beta^2\alpha^2$, but I have no idea other way around. I tried to give counterexamples but I failed and I tried to proof it via division algorithm or Cantor normal form but it becomes hugely massive and I don't think it works.
